# Unit test error: > echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1

Tags: rest, unit-testing, crud

I am writing a unit test for the API crud functionality but I kept getting this error:

> " > echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1":,

I have checked everything including the package.json and test.js file.

This is my package.json file:

[image: this is my package.json file]

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app'); // Adjust the path to point to your app.js

describe('Movies API', () => {
  describe('GET /movies', () => {
    test('should respond with a list of movies', async () => {
      const res = await request(app)
        .get('/movies')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200);

      expect(Array.isArray(res.body)).toBeTruthy();
      expect(res.body.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
      expect(res.body[0]).toHaveProperty('movies_id');
      expect(res.body[0]).toHaveProperty('name');
      expect(res.body[0]).toHaveProperty('genre');
      expect(res.body[0]).toHaveProperty('releaseYear');
      expect(res.body[0]).toHaveProperty('rating');
    });
  });

});

afterAll(() => {
  db.close();
});
```